# Get terms from multiple taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have to get all the terms from four taxonomies:

- vehicle_safely_features
- vehicle_exterior_features
- vehicle_interior_features
- vehicle_extras

I tried this:

```
$terms = get_terms( array( 
    'taxonomy' => 'vehicle_safely_features',
    'vehicle_exterior_features',
    'vehicle_interior_features',
    'vehicle_extras'
) );
```

But, it only gets terms of `vehicle_safely_features` and not all of the taxonomies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to retrieve multiple taxonomies you need to put the four taxonomies in an array, you are doing this, but you have put `taxonomy=>` in the array.

```
$terms = get_terms(
          'taxonomy' => array(
                         'vehicle_safely_features',
                         'vehicle_exterior_features',
                         'vehicle_interior_features',
                         'vehicle_extras')
);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Benoti that did the trick I knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 3):

Incase someone get an error due to the `=>` use below

```
$termsArray = get_the_terms(
    $post->ID,
    array(
        'tax1',
        'tax2',
        'tax3'
    )
)
```

Comment: `get_the_terms` only accepts one taxonomy at a time as a string. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

Answer (score 0):

`wp_get_post_terms` accepts multiple taxonomies as opposed to `get_the_terms` suggested by another answer.

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms(
    $post->ID,
    array(
        'tax1',
        'tax2',
        'tax3'
    )
)
```

**Resource**

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/